# Is there a bounded, closed, uncountable subset of irrational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, irrational-numbers

We can easily find examples of closed and uncountable subset of irrational numbers. What about if we add the condition of the set being bounded?

My first initial reaction was that such a set of not possible. Various approaches to proving it were using the fact that since it's closed and bounded, it must be compact and then claiming something using the existence of a finite subcover. But this hasn't led me to anything.

Is there an example of such a set? If not can we prove why there can't be such a set?

Comment: Also, if there's such a set one place I thought we could find an example is looking at all the irrationals in the cantor set. But how would I prove that that set is closed?

Comment: The cantor set is it.  It's closed because 1) It's an intersection of closed sets and 2) Any point not in the cantor set is not a limit point.

Comment: Oh.  You can offset the cantor set to have only irrational points.

Comment: But doesn't the cantor set also contain rationals ?

Comment: Yes it does. I forgot about that. But if instead of starting on the interval $[0,1]$ you can offset it to have only irrational points.  Maybe.  I think.  Maybe not.

Comment: @Doug M But such a set need not be closed. There could be a sequence of irrational number in the set which converge to a rational

Comment: @SayanChattopadhyay That there is a sequence of irrational numbers that converges to a rational number says that the set is not complete.  It is still closed.

Comment: @Doug M if there exists such a sequence then that would be mean that, that rational number is a limit point of that set. Since the set is said to be closed, it should contain all its limit points. Hence will contain that rational number. My set should contain only irrationals

Comment: @SayanChattopadhyay A set is compact if it contains all of its limit points.  A set can be closed but not compact.

Comment: @Doug M No, the definition of closed set is a set that contains all its limit points.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an alternative to the Cantor set examples, but it requires some measure theory. We can construct an open set of arbitrarily small measure that contains all the rationals by enumerating the rationals and taking the union of open intervals of length $2^{-n}\epsilon$ around the $n$th rational. The complement of this set is then a closed set containing only irrational numbers. If we want a bounded set, just intersect if with a bounded closed interval. As long as that interval's length is larger than $\epsilon$, we're guaranteed to end up with a set of positive measure (and such a set must be uncountable).

On a related note, we can show that if we have an unbounded, uncountable closed set of irrationals then we can construct a bounded set from it. Just take its intersection with each of the unit intervals $[n,n+1]$ for $n\in \mathbb Z$. Since there are only countably many such intervals, at least one of those intersections has to be uncountable.

Answer (score 0):

I have constructed an example

We consider the set $X=\{0.a3bc3def3,\dots:~\text{where} ~a,b,c,d,.... =1~\text{or}~2\}$

Here

```
 the set is bounded.

 the set contains only irrational numbers.

 bounded as each number is $<1$

 the set is uncountable

 and it is obvious that this is closed.
```